# Is there a possibility that these numbers are the same value? Badge reader, rfid

Tags: number-formatting, smartcard, uniqueidentifier, rfid, cardreader

I would need help with these values, I have read many other answers, but none of them have helped me so far.
I have two badge readers showing a different value on screen, and I'm trying to figure out how to get to the value 2 from the original RFID.

These are the numbers that seem completely different to me, also in binary and in hexadecimal, also looking for the presence of prefixes.

RFID: 0009204976

Value 1: **9204976** (rfid without zeros)

Value 2: **73976048**

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Do you consistently get the same IDs on the same reader? There are some schemes, where the UID is randomized, and getting the same even on the identical reader has low probability... Mentioning the rfid technology in question would also make answering easier.

Comment: Hi guidon, yes.. On one badge reader and on the usb reader i get the value 1 but in another older reader and on a dispenser i get always the value 2. Maybe 2 tags in the same badge?

Comment: If this was supposed to supply "the" misssing information - it unfortunately still leaves more gaps than substance. (What nummber base did you use, which NFC tags, ...)

Comment: I've used the RFID to try to get the value 2, from the rfid I can get the Family Number and the card number by splitting the binary value.

Comment: I can give you other examples.. Like Value 1: 4991608 Value 2: 78519928

Comment: I contacted the badge reader company and they confirmed that the badge has only one tag inside. The different value is due to a different decoding being used. Unfortunately they don't want to tell me what kind of decoding is used.